# How to `git filter-repo` to add file to every commit?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Can we use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to add a file to every commit?
I could not figure out a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

An example can be found here:
https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/contrib/filter-repo-demos/insert-beginning

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a file to every commit. You just need to add it to the oldest commit. You can use `git rebase --interactive`. If you want to add the file to the 1st commit you need to rebase from the root commit:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

Add the file, commit and `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: Thats a good answer, but with LFS migration you maybe want to add an `.gitattributes` file everywhere, and your history is HUGE > 60gb.... meaning, rebase == unfeasible

Comment: @Gabriel That limits should have been in the question.

Comment: using rebase is a terrible idea for anything but very simple repos

Comment: @CervEd That's certainly not true.

Comment: @phd yes it is. You have rebase all branches and you have to do it correctly and manually. You have to update all the tags. You can't run it in a bare repository. Every single commit has to be checked out to the working tree. It's not a use-case rebase was designed for. Using `filter-repo` is much more convenient for anything non-trivial

Comment: This is not the same as using git-filter-repo because it will change commit timestamps which is sometimes unwanted.

Comment: @tigrou Well, when it is **sometimes** unwanted then **sometimes** use `git filter-branch` or  `git filter-repo`.

Comment: “You don't need to add a file to every commit.” seems like a very bold statement. I came across this question looking for a way to do `makepkg --printsrcinfo > .SRCINFO; and git add .SRCINFO` for every commit. Doing this just for the initial commit would make `.SRCINFO` wrong from the next commit onwards. I don’t see anything in the question that shows that OP are not in a similar situation, so I’m really curious how you can confidently say they “don't need to add a file to every commit.” Feels like a chance to ask OP for more details rather than making assumptions/blanket statements.